# Stuck with laravel insertion

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a form in which i get fields from another table like, first field is hard coded, and second field is getting from another table, if other table have 10 record then 10 new fields are displayed to user. My question is how can i insert this kind of data in table.

I am getting data like this

```
<label for="membership_id">Membership:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="membership_id" id="membership_id">

        @foreach($pages as $page)
                   <tr>
                   <td><input type="text" name="{{ $page->id }}" value="{{ $page->id }}"></td>
                    <td>{{ $page->title }}</td>

                   <td><label class="checkbox-inline" for="add_page"><input type="checkbox" id="" name="{{$page->id}}}}_status_no" value="0">No </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="add_page"><input type="checkbox" id="" name="{{$page->id}}}}_status_yes" value="1">Yes </label></td>
                   </tr>
                    @endforeach  

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

how can i get this kind of data in my controller and then save data in database

Answer (score 0):

**View**

```
<form method="POST">
<label for="membership_id">Membership:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="membership_id" id="membership_id">

@foreach($pages as $page)
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="page[{{ $page->id }}][id]" value="{{ $page->id }}">
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ $page->title }}
    </td>

    <td>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="add_page">
        <input type="checkbox" name="page[{{ $page->id }}][status]" value="0">No </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="add_page">
        <input type="checkbox" name="page[{{ $page->id }}][status]" value="1">Yes </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach  

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
foreach(Input::get('page') as $page){
  if(!empty($page['id']) && !empty($page['status']){
    $page = Page::find($page['id']);
    $page->status = $page['status'];
    $page->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Creating default object from empty value this error occure